# WiFi not available after Ubuntu fresh installation

Tags: internet

I had a problem while installing Ubuntu and now that I have installed Ubuntu, the WiFi driver is not installed on my laptop and I have to connect my laptop to the Internet with a wire. How can I install WiFi driver on Labtab? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Good morning, you will have to provide some more information so others can help you. Are you dual booting with Windows? Did you make sure that your BIOS/UEFI is set to UEFI and that Secure Boot is disabled? When you installed Ubuntu, did you check the box to download third party software? Please edit the answers into your question. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your system using Ethernet cabel just type `sudo apt update and after upgrade` if isn't help remove your old driver and try to install again.